# CSS. How to add small image on background?

Tags: image, css, background, gradient

I'm creating custom (gradient) buttons with CSS. When button is clicked on, it should appear small arrow (arrow.gif). It worked before when I used `background-color:` property. Now I use:

```
a.nav_selected:link, a.nav_selected:visited {
    display:block;
    float:left; 
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0;
    width: auto;
    margin:0px 14px 0px 14px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none; 
    color: black; 
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 14px 0px 14px;
    background:url(images/arrow.gif) no-repeat top center;
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCBA2A 0%, #FFE3A3 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCBA2A 0%, #FFE3A3 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCBA2A 0%, #FFE3A3 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCBA2A 0%, #FFE3A3 100%);
    opacity: 0.85;  
}
```

If I use `background:url(images/arrow.gif) no-repeat top center;` in the bottom of code (after background-image:...) then arrow appears, but here is no gradient background. How to make that appeared and arrow and background? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Now my code looks like:

```
a.nav_selected:link, a.nav_selected:visited {
display:block;
float:left; 
padding:0px; 
margin:0;
width: auto;
margin:0px 14px 0px 14px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none; 
color: black; 
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 14px 0px 14px;
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCBA2A 0%, #FFE3A3 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCBA2A 0%, #FFE3A3 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCBA2A 0%, #FFE3A3 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCBA2A 0%, #FFE3A3 100%);
opacity: 0.85;  
position: relative;
}
a.nav_selected:link:after,
a.nav_selected:visited:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 7px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background:url(images/arrow.gif) no-repeat top center;
}
```

But I got the same problem, only gradient background appears, here is no animated arrow.

Comment: you overwrite the `background:url(images/arrow.gif) no-repeat top center;`with `background-image`

Comment: There is no cross-browser method to use multiple background images. The browser treats the gradient as a background image.

Comment: Thank you for answers, so there is no way to make that?

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė please see my answer and associated jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser treats the background gradients as a background image. When you add your first definition of `background`, you're overwriting the subsequent `background-image` properties, since it's more specific.

If you're just looking to add a drop-down indicator to the link, you might want to look at using the `:after` pseudo-element.

Add the following CSS rule to your `a.nav_selected:link` and `a.nav_selected:visited` CSS:

```
position: relative;
```

And then add a new rule as follows:

```
a.nav_selected:link:after,
a.nav_selected:visited:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 7px;
    content: '';
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background:url(images/arrow.gif) no-repeat top center;
}
```

Here's a [<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/AQfU9/)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but for now It show arrows as in your example (black triangle) my arrow is animated and It now appears.

Comment: You can set the background of the `:after` element to include your image.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I misunderstood how to do that correctly?

Comment: I updated my question with code how It looks like now. I got the same problem, only gradient background appears.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the answer. I forgot to mention that you need to specify a with and height for `:after` to work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this

```
background:url(images/arrow.gif) no-repeat top center;

to

background-image:url(images/arrow.gif) no-repeat top center;
```

Comment: `no-repeat top center` can not be part of the `background-image` property